# Position image left of Bootstrap container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to build a simple web page and I need an image to be positioned on the left of the container. Ideally I'd like to make sure the image resize nicely when the browser window is resized but still keeps its position independently from the text. What I'm trying to achieve looks something like this:

[image]

The text part is inside the Bootstrap container CSS class. Not sure how to achieve the look I need - tried a few things with image being inside a wrapper with absolute position on the same level as the container div, but then I can't seem to center the image inside the wrapper (vertically).

This is what I have so far:

```css
.header {
 background-color: #333333;
}

.logo-wrapper {
 position: absolute;
}

.logo {
    position: relative;
    /* padding-top: 50%; */
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
 <div class="header">
      <div class="logo-wrapper">
        <img src="assets/logo.png" class="logo">
      </div>
      <div class="container">
        <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</h1>
        <h3>Sed tristique augue turpis, ullamcorper convallis augue fermentum vel. Cras a tempus nulla. Vestibulum congue sollicitudin vulputate</h3>
        <h2> Integer vitae tortor id elit pharetra dignissim</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: We will need some code to be able to help you out. This is too vague

Comment: Can you please add code which you have try..

Comment: there's literally no code that worked yet. ok I'll add what I have

Comment: done, there's some code now. class container is from Bootstrap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.logo-wrapper {
     width: 20%;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    
}
.logo-wrapper img{
    max-width:100%
}

.container{
  width:80%;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
      <div class="logo-wrapper">
        <img src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2015/03/04/22/35/head-659652_640.png" class="logo">
      </div>
      <div class="container">
        <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</h1>
        <h3>Sed tristique augue turpis, ullamcorper convallis augue fermentum vel. Cras a tempus nulla. Vestibulum congue sollicitudin vulputate</h3>
        <h2> Integer vitae tortor id elit pharetra dignissim</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that's not working for me.. The image appears in the top left corner, it's not vertically centred to look in-line with the container and if resized, it gets shrunk without keeping the aspect ration...

Comment: Ok so you want vertically  center also give me time

Comment: Thanks! I've modified your suggestion by adding another 20% empty element to the right of the container (20/60/20 split) so that my container is always in the middle. Plus added the image alignment to the center of the div to get the look I was looking for. Seems to be working now!

Answer (score 0):

```css
.header {
 background-color: #333333;
  line-height:1.5em;
  display:inline;
}
.container{
 float:right;  
  width:70%;
  padding-left:10%;
}
.logo-wrapper {
 float:left;
    width:20%;   
}
.logo-wrapper img{
    max-width:100%
}
}
.logo {
    position: relative;
    /* padding-top: 50%; */
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
      <div class="logo-wrapper">
        <img src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2015/03/04/22/35/head-659652_640.png" class="logo">
      </div>
      <div class="container">
        <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</h1>
        <h3>Sed tristique augue turpis, ullamcorper convallis augue fermentum vel. Cras a tempus nulla. Vestibulum congue sollicitudin vulputate</h3>
        <h2> Integer vitae tortor id elit pharetra dignissim</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I think the answer of @Mitul is correct. But there's a slight modification in the solution of Mitul. If you want no text below the image, you should modify it like.

Comment: It is advised that, you better put all content into container and then seperate  contents with grid structure of bootstrap. That will enhance your ease of controlling contents. And off course, that's the standard way.

Comment: Your solution didn't really work for me - float right just pushes all the content off the screen completely.

I thought about using the grid inside the container, however I'm not sure how to do that and still keep the text perfectly align in the middle of the screen (horizontally)

Comment: I think the container is going off the screen, because your width criteria is not mentioned really and float may not be a problem. You may see, width is in percentage. So it will take the width of its parent tag.

Comment: By the way, grid structure is really very useful and easy to use also. You may refer some bootstrap tutorials on w3schools.com That's a nice tutorial site.

Comment: You're probably right - I'm so rusty with CSS - can't remember even the simple things.. And last time I used bootstrap I don't think even Bower was a thing yet.. Anyways, thanks for help